# Should I convert Unix time stamp in an "hour" time stamp?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm using PHP and MySQL.

I need to store a unix time stamp each time one of my users accomplish a given action.  I only need an hourly detail level.  Is there any reason why I shouldn't reduce storage by storing something like `(integer)(time()/3600)` instead of the full time stamp?  I need to do multiple queries on this time stamp per session per user.

If I save the time stamp as is, I plan to store it as an `INT` in MySQL.  I'll need to create an index combining userID and time stamp.

If I convert the time stamp into a number of hours, I can store it as a `MEDIUMINT` in MySQL.

Comment: An int is an int, and takes as much space as an int takes, no matter what value you store.  Store a smallint instead, and you'll save half the space.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html   int v.s. timestamp = no difference. They both use 4 bytes. If you're so constrained in space that reducing to a 2byte medium int will save your system, then you seriously need to throw another $10 onto the budget to get a bigger harddrive. disk space is cheap. the cost of moving to non-native storage types will burn up far more down the road than you'll save now.

Comment: As always, I completely agree with @MarcB.  A saving of 2B per record translates to (just under) 2MiB per million records, or 2GiB per billion records.  With 1TiB of storage costing around $40 and providing additional storage for almost half a trillion extra records, it's hard to imagine why this optimisation is worthwhile.

Answer (score 1):

Well. One reason: Unless the timestamp is saved as a string, or we are past year 2038 it will not actually use less space.

Comment: I'm saving the time stamp as an `INT`.

Comment: An INT uses the same amount of space, no matter what integer is saved.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this will reduce space in a database if you on a table have under 5 millons inserts of timestamp data. In other way you didn't need but for a performance save as unsigned (10) integer in database instead timestamp or date/time. This will be produce faster of indexing and searching a data.

Comment: Please provide evidence for this: I don't believe you are correct.  As an integer is 4-bytes, and a timestamp is 4-bytes, then the data size is identical, and the speed of indexing/searching should also be identical

Comment: It's on storage engines situations, look at topic: http://gpshumano.blogs.dri.pt/2009/07/06/mysql-datetime-vs-timestamp-vs-int-performance-and-benchmarking-with-myisam/ This cause of filesystem cache flush.